# Does a matrix with a determinant of zero equal to having no determinant? Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I know that a matrix with a determinant of zero means the matrix is invertible. But I have difficulties with grasping the concept of "no determinant". Does it also mean that only non-square matrices that have no determinant?

Comment: The determinant is defined for square matrices.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  A determinant of zero means the matrix is *not* invertible

Comment: Determinant zero means *not* invertible. It has nothing to with not having a determinant. You are right that determinant is not defined for square matrices. Also, it isn't necessarily defined for square matrices with entries in a noncommutative ring,

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip "You are right that determinant is not defined for square matrices." I think there's a typo there ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber: indeed I meant it is not defined for non-square matrices. Thanks.

Comment: A small amendment to @CheerfulParsnip's statement "Also, it isn't necessarily defined for square matrices with entries in a noncommutative ring" - there are indeed notions of determinant for matrices with entries in non-commutative rings, but they're quite messy and should be ignored for now until the classical case (matrices with real numbers as entries - to the OP, in a bit of jargon which one will need to understand to fully "get" the topic, these represent *linear transformations of finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-spaces*) is well-understood.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your first sentence is incorrect: having a determinant of zero means the matrix is *not* invertible, and indeed the two are equivalent.

---

As to the difference between having determinant equal to zero and having no determinant, at the simplest level the determinant is *only defined for* square matrices: every square matrix has a determinant (possibly zero, possibly nonzero), and no non-square matrix has a determinant.

Now one might ask, "Why do we only define the determinant for square matrices?" I think the simplest answer is to remember that matrices are representations of linear maps - an $n$-by-$m$ matrix representing a linear map from an $m$-dimensional space to an $n$-dimensional space - and when $m=n$ it makes sense to ask how this map "distorts volume." E.g. in the setting $m=n=2$, the matrix $2I$ (where $I$ is the 2-dimensional identity matrix) represents the transformation which doubles the length (while not changing the direction) of every vector. This changes a rectangle of area $A$ into a rectangle of area $4A$, and the determinant is the ratio ${4A\over A}=4$.

But when $m\not=n$ this doesn't really make sense: if $m<n$ then *every* linear map transforms the whole domain into a set with zero $n$-dimensional volume *(think about how a plane in $3$-space has no volume)*, and if $m>n$ then the $n$-dimensional volume of the image of an $m$-dimensional rectangle need not be determined by the $m$-dimensional volume of that rectangle *(think about a projection map from $3$-space to $2$-space, and the non-difference between what happens to a "tall" prism versus a "short" prism)*. So if $m\not=n$, either the determinant is a silly notion *(if $m<n$)* or isn't even guaranteed to be well-defined *(if $m>n$; indeed, if $m>n$ then this will only be well-defined in the case when our map sends everything to the zero vector!)*.

(See also [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811951/why-is-it-important-for-a-matrix-to-be-square/2811960#2811960). Additionally, down the road you may be interested in further discussion of what the determinant "actually is," possibly in much more general contexts; there are a few discussions of this here and at mathoverflow.)

---

Note that here I'm omitting any discussion of what the entries of our matrix are. While important (to put it mildly!), I think bringing in that sort of generality at this point will only confuse matters. But it is important to note that $(1)$ we can consider matrices with entries not just from $\mathbb{R}$ but from an arbitrary "number system," like the complex numbers *(specifically, I'm referring to [fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)))*, and $(2)$ we can go to even further levels of generality but then things break down *(e.g. we can, and often do, consider matrices with entries from an arbitrary ring, but then [the "determinant" idea gets much more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasideterminant#Connections_to_other_determinants))*.

Comment: @Bungo Gaaaaaaah! Fixed, thanks. I can *never* remember which way that goes.